# FabricInvalidAddressException: NamedEndpoint 'V2Listener' when trying to connect from .NET Core application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm am trying to connect to a Service Fabric application using the `ServiceProxy` class like so:

```
return ServiceProxy.Create<ISomeService>(
    new Uri("fabric:/SomeService.App/ISomeService"), 
    new ServicePartitionKey(0));
```

When I do this from a .Net Framework application everything works fine.

However, when I try this from a .Net Core application I get the following error:

> InnerException = {System.Fabric.FabricInvalidAddressException: NamedEndpoint 'V2Listener' not found in the address '{"Endpoints":{"":"..."}}' for partition '...')

I'm assuming this has something to do with V2 remoting, but I can't figure out what exactly it is in the .Net Core project that is defaulting it to use V2 instead of V1.

Is there a way I can force it to use V1 - I'm not in a position to upgrade the target service to V2 at the moment.

All applications involved are using Service Fabric version 6.1.480

Only relevant documentation I can find is [Service Fabric Reliable Services Communication Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting) and it hasn't helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use SF Remoting V2 in .Net Core.
Remoting V1 is supported using Full Framework only. (I agree that the documentation should specify this.)

See this [link](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/815)

Comment: Thanks, this isn't clear at all from the documentation