# Call service via remoting V1 with Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting 3.2.162

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-remoting

I've multiple services using remoting V1 and new services with V2_1.

Calling the V2_1 services from a asp.net core 2.1 application using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting version 3.2.162 is no problem.
But I cannot call the "old" V1 services, because it tries to connect via V2_1. The first time it throws an exception:

```
NamedEndpoint 'V2_1Listener' not found in the address '{"Endpoints":{"":"DESKTOP-XX:33016+086fcdfa-9eba-49e0-8953-6fae844d8cf0-131779318708109471-d1b542d1-71bb-40a8-b22d-d0aabc9f4f5c"}}' for partition '086fcdfa-9eba-49e0-8953-6fae844d8cf0'
```

And the second time it hangs, and usages a lot of CPU usages.

The [workaround](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/570#issuecomment-339632715) creating a custom ServiceProxyFactory is not working anymore because the namespace Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V1 is remove in 3.2.162

So I decided to upgrade a V1 service with added a extra V2_1 listener, following the [upgrade steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#how-to-upgrade-from-remoting-v1-to-remoting-v2interfacecompatible). But again after coping this line:

```
 [assembly: FabricTransportServiceRemotingProvider(RemotingListenerVersion = RemotingListenerVersion.V2_1 | RemotingListenerVersion.V1, RemotingClientVersion = RemotingClientVersion.V2_1)]
```

RemotingListenerVersion.V1 is not found.

I cannot simple change the V1 listener to V2_1 because other services are depending on it.

What should I do? Is it possible to use V1 and V2_1 altogether? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: It should be possible. make sure the code that is calling the v1 services do not use any of the classes in the v2 remoting namespaces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Service Fabric Remoting V2 is not supported in .NET Core.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756171/fabricinvalidaddressexception-namedendpoint-v2listener-when-trying-to-connect?rq=1) I can't believe that it is not documented.

In my case, I had a domain project targeting .NET Standard 2.0, and the service project was referencing that package and targeting .NET 4.6.2.

Therefore, I changed the migration plan:

1. Made sure the domain/interface projects are targeting a full .NET framework,
   e.g., .NET 6.4.2
2. [Added a V2_1 listener next to the current V1 listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#how-to-upgrade-from-remoting-v1-to-remoting-v2interfacecompatible).
3. Updated all the clients, so they are using V2_1
4. Removed the V1 listener and switched our project back to .NET Standard